# How to update in-app content?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, updates

I'm creating an Android application (for now) using Cordova. The app content is mostly a bunch of HTML pages and images, wrapped together by a index.html and some javascript.

I want to update these HTML pages if possible, when new content is added. The HTML pages will be automatically generated and placed on a server.

Now how do I get these inside my app, without pushing out a new version every time? Is there something like a subversion library which can update content that has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a call to server using jquery ajax get the html content and write it to the file using Cordova file plugin here is the [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter) for writing files.

Secondly, you can make use of jquery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to directly call the html page from server